# Can't retrieve data from a Firebase's node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing an Android app and I'm using Firebase as database. 
I want to get a specific node from the but I'm failing to retrieve these data.

I've written Firebase's security rules and this is my data structure:

[image]

This is my Android code:

```
public void connect() {
    //setting connexion parameter
    final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/test");
    Query query = ref.orderByChild("longitude").equalTo("150");


    //get the data from th DB
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //checking if the user exist
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    //get each user which has the target username
                    final Location location = userSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);

                    //if the password is true , the data will be storaged in the sharedPreferences file and a Home activity will be launched

                    System.out.println("hello map"+location.getLongitude());

                }

                System.out.println("not found");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("problem ");

        }
    });


}
```

and this is the location class

```
public class Location {
private String  longitude,latitude;
public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String  longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Location{" +
            "longitude=" + longitude +
            ", latitude=" + latitude +
            '}';
}

public Location(String longitude, String latitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.latitude = latitude;
}
```

}

Comment: define an empty constructor in your location class.

Comment: i tried it but it dosen't works

Comment: Your query is looking for a variable equal to 150, and I don't see how your query can retrieve something with the current dataset you show. You have an exception?

Comment: i change it to 105 but it dosen't work :) the problem is that the nodes where not inserted with hashmap